# How to alert user if no file was uploaded in Rad File explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show an alert message if no file was uploaded in rad file explorer.
.I want to show this alert when users Press the upload button on Rad file explorer uploadPopup
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Finally i found solution at http://aadyakrishna.blogspot.in/2014/06/show-alert-message-if-no-file-was.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by:

```
var explorer = $find("<%# myFileExplorer.ClientID %>");
    if(explorer.get_fileList().get_items().length == 0)
        alert("Please select a file");
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for reply in which client event i need to attach this function.I want to show this alert when users Press the upload button on Rad file explorer upload Popup